# please help with this error : Operator '^' cannot be applied to operands of type 'double' and 'int'

Tags: c#

i have the following C# code.

```
double a = 0;
 double d = 0;
double er = 0;
int N = numbers.Length;
a=(N*N/6) + N
d=(N-(N/2))*2



     for(int aa=1;aa<=data.length;aa++)
        {

              er=((10-aa)*(-a\) + d - (numbers[aa,12]))^2;

          }
```

numbers is a double array with this format :

```
1 0.3232 0.361 0.5214 0.233 -0.7678
2 0.3451 0.321 0.134 0.224 -0.706268
3 0.3123 0.351 0.155 0.523 -0.70626
4 0.36 0.312 0.216 0.233 -0.6453351
5 0.269 0.3331 0.162 0.224 -0.584962
```

but when running the code , i got this error on this line:

```
 er=((10-aa)*(-a\) + d - (numbers[aa,12]))^2;
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 13):

Use [`Math.Pow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow.aspx) - the `^` is **not** the power operator, it is a [logical XOR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkacc7k1.aspx) operator.

There is no power operator in c#.

Comment: Also start your FOR loop at 0, not 1

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're intending to use the `^` operator for, but in C,C++, and C# it is the `xor` operator.  Its not defined for non-integral types.  If youre trying to do an exponential, you're better off using something like Math.pow() or doing the multiplication yourself